# BackButton pressed Issue

Tags: android, back-button

I am facing a problem of back button. In my application I want to implement a functionality that when the user clicks on the back button it should move on to the Home screen. For doing this I have written a code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            if(backCount==0){
                backCount++;
            Intent restartResearchActivity = new Intent(ResearchListNew.this,ResearchListNew.class);
            startActivity(restartResearchActivity);

            }

            else{



            }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

I have used a static varialble int backCount=0 so that when the user is on the Home screen itself and wants to come out of the APP , then he should move to the else part of the above loop and should not again be prompted to the Home screen,

But suppose first time I used back button it worked correctly and backcount will be = 1 now then , after that If user clicks on the back button it will not move to the home screen as now backcount is greater than 0.

So kindly help me in this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you starting new activity using intent? Instead of reseting the view?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of how nested your Activities are, but if just the one activity, you can try calling finish() on it and that will kill the Activity and bring you back to whatever Activity was up before hand. It's pretty much what the back button does by default.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use onKeyDown or override BackPressed Functionality.

Follow the code, it will work

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();


startActivity(new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class));
}
```

Enjoy!!!